# Use Regex in application.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

is there a way I can write regex in **aplication.yml**

```
origin: '^(.*\.|)example\.com$/'
```

~> something like this
and call it in config **application.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
        allow do
            origins ENV['origin']
            debugger
            resource '*',
                     headers: :any,
                     methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head]
        end
    end
```

Comment: A regex has to be evaluated. Where is the evaluation happening? Imagine you put that regex directly into application.rb, would it do anything? Also This would only be evaluated when Rails is first run, at least in production. Can you explain why you want a regex? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Beartech thanks for the reply the situation is that i am using cors and i have subdomain coz i am using multitenancy (apartment gem) so in the configuration, for different environments, I need to pass subdomain as the wild card

Answer (score 1):

`ENV['origin']` look like you want to use an environment variable. So, ENV would better than YML for that.

```
#Gemfile
gem 'dotenv-rails'

#.env
origin = '^(.*\.|)example\.com$/'

#application.rb
...
origins ENV['origin']
...
```

Answer (score 1):

`Psych` (<= 1.9 `Syck`) ruby's native `YAML` parser can handle transformation of certain ruby objects given they are notated correctly e.g.

```
origin: !ruby/regexp /^(.*\\.|)example\\.com$/
```

converts to a true `Regexp` on load.

```
require 'yaml'

yml = <<-YML
  origin: !ruby/regexp /^(.*\\.|)example\\.com$/
YML

h = YAML.load(yml)
#=> {"origin"=>/^(.*\.|)example\.com$/}

'test.example.com'.match?(h["origin"])
#=> true
```

In order to determine the appropriate syntax one can use `YAML.dump` e.g.

```
YAML.dump(/^(.*\.|)example\.com$/)
#=> "--- !ruby/regexp /^(.*\\.|)example\\.com$/\n...\n"
```

**Please note this only works for certain objects that can be appropriately converted to and from `YAML` values**

Additionally the `Regexp` class can convert strings into `Regexp` objects so the following will also work

```
require 'yaml'

# note we omit the forward slashes 
yml = <<-YML
  origin: ^(.*\\.|)example\\.com$
YML

h = YAML.load(yml)
#=> {"origin"=>"^(.*\\.|)example\\.com$"

'test.example.com'.match?(Regexp.new(h["origin"])) 
#=> true
```

Comment: "YAML can handle transformation..." No YAML cannot do so. Your ruby parser can instantiate ruby objects or function based on the `!ruby/...` tag and hand the tagged node as parameter to the object or function instantiation possible resulting in a transformed node. That is 99% ruby, 1% parser and 0% YAML, as the latter doesn't know anything about what could happen by a tagged object (a  tag `!ruby` only appears, once, as an example of how a node  *could* be mapped to a native data structure, in the specification.)

Comment: With Python (with which YAML parser I am more familiar) you can essentially always thinly wrap something (regex or else), in such a way that your wrapper gets the information from the parser if a node is tagged `!wrapper` and then hand it to wrapped function in any specific way the function expects. I assume you can do the same in Ruby. I

Comment: @Anthon unfortunately I am far less familiar with `python` but if you were to provide some kind of an example I am certain i could implement the same in `ruby` however I feel this sufficiently answers the question posed (*"is there a way I can write regex in aplication.yml"*)